# Move the "Reset zoom" button in Network profile reputation graph to the left

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph, network-profile

Would it be worthwhile to move the reset over to the left, in the multi-site reputation chart on stackexhange.com? Rationale is as follows: The graph keeps growing towards the right and there is then nearly always space of the left top corner. That is unless somebody flatlines on one of the sites.

[image: Image showing the current and proposed location of reset zoom]
**Image 1:** Current and proposed location of reset zoom button, using [my own graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/1407800/joojaa?tab=reputation).

An additional benefit would be that the reset would be easier to hit on some of the smaller smartphones.

This change should be quite trivial to implement. However I am aware that right side is better so as a alternative location I suggest placing it above the legend.

Comment: Interesting that these graphs use the default plot colours from Microsoft Excel. Well, maybe not interesting, really.